# Only remove a folder on uninstall, not upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to configure an inherited WiX installer for use with my software.

The software logs to day-specific files in C:\SomePath\LogFiles like 2014-05-19.txt, 2014-05-18.txt, and so on (not really relevant to question, but perhaps worth noting that there will be files present that are created by the software, but not by the installer itself).

My WiX installer creates the LogFiles directory like this (lots of elements, GUIDs etc removed for readability):

```
<Wix>
    <Product Id="SOME_GUID" Version="SOME_VERSION" UpgradeCode="OTHER_GUID">
        <Feature Id="EMPTY_DIRECTORIES" Title="Empty Directories" Level="1" Display="hidden">
            <ComponentRef Id="SomeFolder" />
            <ComponentRef Id="LogFiles" />
            <ComponentRef Id="SomeOtherFolder" />
        </Feature>
        <DirectoryRef Id="DIR_LOG_FILES">
            <Component Guid="" Id="DELETE_DIR_LOG_FILES">
                <RemoveFile Id="DELETE_DIR_LOG_FILES_FILES" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" /> 
                <RemoveFolder Id="DELETE_DIR_LOG_FILES" On="uninstall" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
     </Product>
     <Fragment>
         <Directory Name="SoftwareName" Id="SOFTWARENAME">
             <Directory Id="DIR_LOG_FILES" Name="LogFiles">
                 <Component Id="LogFiles" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no" Permanent="no" Win64="no" Location="local">
                     <CreateFolder>
                         <util:PermissionEx CreateChild="yes" CreateFile="yes" Delete="yes" Read="yes" ReadAttributes="yes" ReadExtendedAttributes="yes" ReadPermission="yes" Traverse="yes" GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" User="Everyone" />
                      </CreateFolder>
                  </Component>
              </Directory>
           </Directory>
      </Fragment>
      <Fragment>
          <ComponentGroup Id="LoggingComponents" Directory="WHERE_THE_LOGGING_DLLS_LIVE">
              <ComponentRef Id="DELETE_DIR_LOG_FILES" />
          </ComponentGroup>
      </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I had hoped that this setup would cause the directory and contents to be deleted only on uninstall. Unfortunately the deletion seems to trigger on upgrade as well. Is there a way to configure WiX to tell the difference and react appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

In your build process do you update the version of the dll's you want to produce as that should overwrite it. Do you have any remove file/folder tags as they could also cause an issue.

Comment: Yes, DLL versions are updated.  But DLLs live ensewhere. I have RemoveFile and RemoveFolder as shown above, with the On attribute set to "Uninstall"